# Is any answer in this question an answer?

Tags: discussion

[Trying to calculate percents with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429514/trying-to-calculate-percents-with-java/32429558)

2 of these answers try to answer the question and provide good pratices, but also provide wrong information. (Both of them havent run the OP's code, and assume the problem lies in integer conversion where the whole calulation run ins double)

1 answer is simply a wall of code.

What is the appropriate action in this kind of scenario ? Is moderator intervention necessary in this kind of "mess" ?

Comment: Put downvotes with a comment along? I don't see a reason why this needs to be brought up on Meta-SO.

Comment: Idk, this could be seen examplary for a question where all answers are wrong. If anyone stumples upon it and tries the "solutions" then he will be really confused. And they are already upvoted, eventhough they are wrong. Also I don't know when it's approporiate to call moderators, because I would rather not waste their time.

Comment: Wrong answer that attempts to solve the stated problem is still an answer.

Comment: Overall for whole question - I think vote to close as typographical error or find duplicate for "don't put `;` after `for`" - both would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save for the wall of code, they're all attempts at an answer.

- One addresses a typo which leads to the scenario that they're observing; the loop only runs once.
- Two addresses a potential issue with integer division, even if it's not quite correct as authored.

The wall of code should be commented on at least; I've already left some remarks.  However, all of them are still attempts at an answer.

In general, you want to call a moderator in for a scenario in which the community can't handle; that is, this is something that requires above and beyond privileges.  This isn't anything that would rise to that sort of scenario, so there's no reason for mods to get involved.  In fact, since they're not to be regarded as subject matter experts, they may even decline your flag(s), indicating that one can't flag a moderator over technical inaccuracies.

Comment: @pnuts:  With the proviso that a wall of code isn't an answer, it looks like you've got it pretty well down pat.

Comment: @pnuts:  Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)